# Using onchange function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner in javascript. I got an assignment to know about onchange keyword in javascript. i had seen this function is using different controls. I was unable where exactly to use this function.
what is onchange() in javascript? and for which controls we will use ? why will use in onchange() ?
please Explain in briefly with example?

Comment: There is something called documentation, why don't you refer that?

Comment: which documentation? can you send link of the documentation

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Why don't you search it on google???

Answer (score 2):

The `onchange` property is fired when the element loses the focus or the content of the element have changed since the last time. It works `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements

Here is an example of `onchange` applied on `input type='text'`

**JS**

```
function showContent(elem) {
  var value = elem.value;
  alert(value)
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" onchange="showContent(this)">
```

Here the `onchange` event eill fire as soon as `tab` or focus out of the element
You can use `onchange` with other input type like radio,checkbox,file

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0u60vp74/)